# How to completely migrate Windows Server VMs with no access to hypervisor?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, kvm-virtualization, migration, vmware-vsphere

There are two Windows Server VMs (2008R2 & 2012R2) hosted on OVH (via VMware I think).

I would like to move away both VMs from OVH to my server running KVM VMs.

OVH isn't going to give me any images of VMs to download. I only have full admin rights from within the VMs.

What would be the best way to do this so I don't have to reinstall or set anything up (VMs contain bunch of installed software, settings, users, etc which would take many days to re-create)?

Comment: Step 1: Talk to their customer support. Step 2: decide. THEY have access and THEY can make an export/backup/whatever. Alternative: read up on how to make a backup. Windows has tools for that ;) Then you can try to restore into a separate VM on another host.

Comment: @TomTom, thanks for the response! I did ask them but basically they do not have any support at all, but let's hope they'll respond. Regarding the backup: I actually did try this with the built in Windows Backup tool but when restoring the backup - the VM becomes unbootable (I assume because of different hypervisors & boot disks). I'll keep trying though...

Comment: Installing your software, settings, users, etc., should already be automated, so that it takes minutes to do this, not days.

Comment: @MichaelHampton unfortunately this is not the case and I need to find a way to migrate the VMs with what I have now.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You must be joking? Automation costs time. Unless you do manage serverS - with capital S for a significant plural - it is wasted time.

Comment: @TomTom It's only wasted time if your automation tools suck, or you _never_ run into situations like the above. I _have_, and I found that even automating a single server was worth it in the long run.